# Create a breadcrumb in javascript with parent relation

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to show a breadcrumb style title where each child would be associated with multiple parents

I have this data structure

```
const modelData = {
  course: {
    id: 'courseUUID1',
    chapters: ['12345', '678910'],
    title: 'course 1'
  },

  // Chapters are children of course as you see above in chapters array
  chapters: [
    { 
      id: '12345',
      sections: ['88999', '9999888'],
      title: 'chapter 1'
    },
    { 
      id: '678910',
      sections: [],
      title: 'chapter 2'
    }
  ],

  // section is a child of chapters as you see above in array
  sections: [
    {
      id: '88999',
      title: 'Section 1'
    },
    {
      id: '9999888',
      title: 'Section 2'
    }
  ]
}
```

So what the end result should look like if I just console titles of each model it should show me this

Course -> title: Course 1

Chapter-> title: `Course 1 | chapter 1`

section: -> title: `Course 1 | chapter 1 | section 1`

So to explain this further >>>
each child should include the title of all of its subsequent parents. as in the example above
the `section` is a child of `chapter` and `chapter` is a child of `course`

the outer most parent will have no modifications in title

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally same chapter not repeating in course or book.

This snippet based hierarchy wise, maybe bit helpful.

```js
const modelData = [ 
    { "title" : "Course 1", "id" : "courseUUID1", "children" : [
        { "title" : "Chapter 1", "id" : "12345", "children" : [
            { "title" : "Section 1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : []},
            { "title" : "Section 2", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : []},
        ]}
    ]},
];


let index = {};

function buildIndex(root, children) {
    for(var i in children) {
        index[children[i].title] = root;
        buildIndex(children[i].title, children[i].children);
    }
}

buildIndex("Book", modelData);

function getIndex(idx) {
    return index[idx] ? getIndex(index[idx]).concat([idx]) : [idx];
}

console.log(  getIndex("Section 2")  );
//Check Console ["Book", "Course 1", "Chapter 1", "Section 2"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I converted my original data structure as to how yours is and it works exactly how I want it to.